# Is Dead Snow 2: Red vs. Dead (Død snø 2) entirely in Norwegian?

Tags: alternate-version, dead-snow-2

I've purchased [Dead Snow 2: Red vs. Dead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2832470/) blu-ray, the film is in English and I wonder if I have received a dubbed version or if the movie was recorded in English. [The original Dead Snow](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1278340/) has only Norwegian-language dialogue as far as I remember.

Answer (score 2):

According to [**IMDB**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2832470/alternateversions?ref_=ttgf_sa_4)

> In English-speaking countries the film was released in an English-only version. For this, all Norwegian dialogue scenes were also shot in English.

So it seems scenes were shot in both languages.

Comment: I'd like a verification if the scenes were actually reshot, or just dubbed over. Imdb isn't alone unfortunately a completely reliable source.

Comment: If you have the DVD...I'd check the credits. It would be in there....but otherwise, I'm not sure what other "official" confirmation you are going to get. Dubbed movies are usually pretty obvious.

Comment: You could try contacting the production companies if it's a real concern - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2832470/companycredits?ref_=tt_dt_co